# how do i add vectors to a (Vegan package) ordihull plot?

Tags: r, vector, plot, vegan

how do i add vectors (illustrating annual change) to a ordihull plot?
I have created a ordihull plot illustrating the years 2011, 2013 and 2015 each with it's own colour. now i would like to see if all locations change in the same direction or if they move randomly. statistically i found a significant change on axis 3, therefore i want to apply vectors amplifying this change. The change is not apparent from the plot as it is now.[Ordihull plot of 3 years](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrE35.jpg)

My script:

```
library(vegan)
matrix_s = read.table('matrix_s.txt', sep = "\t", header = TRUE)
matrixfit4 <- metaMDS(matrix_s, k=4, trymax=50, distance="bray")
ordiplot(matrixfit4,display = "site",type="p",choices = c(2,3))
ordihull(matrixfit4, K4Full$Year, display = "sites", show.groups = "2011",col= c("purple"),choices = c(2,3), draw = "polygon")
ordihull(matrixfit4, K4Full$Year, display = "sites", show.groups = "2013",col= c("red"), choices = c(2,3),draw = "polygon")
ordihull(matrixfit4, K4Full$Year, display = "sites", show.groups = "2015",col= c("orange"),choices = c(2,3), draw = "polygon")
legend(-1.195, 1.555, unique(K4Full$Year), text.col =c("purple","red","orange"),cex=1)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For the R tag we ask that you provide reproducible examples, so please include data via a builtin dataset or via `dput()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe vectors are the correct approach here; how can one think of a direction of *increasing amounts of year==2013*? For categorical variables like this it is more natural to think of centroids in ordination space.

For example, consider this illustration using the built-in Dutch dune meadows data

```
library("vegan")

data(dune, dune.env)
set.seed(42)
ord <- metaMDS(dune)

cols <- c("purple","red","orange","black")
plot(ord, type = "n")
with(dune.env, points(ord, col = cols[Management]))
with(dune.env, ordihull(ord, Management, col = cols))

ev <- envfit(ord ~ Management, data = dune.env)
plot(ev, add = TRUE)
```

This will give you a plot like this:

[image: non-metric multidimensional scaling plot showing convex hulls for farm management type]

The `envfit()` function contains one test of a `Management` effect

```
> ev

***FACTORS:

Centroids:
               NMDS1   NMDS2
ManagementBF -0.4534 -0.0102
ManagementHF -0.2636 -0.1282
ManagementNM  0.2958  0.5790
ManagementSF  0.1506 -0.4670

Goodness of fit:
               r2 Pr(>r)   
Management 0.4134  0.004 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999
```

What this is doing is testing whether the sum of squared deviations from the group centroids explains more variation than under a null model of no grouping, where we would have sum of squared deviations from the overall centroids of the data. The centroids are with respect to the two NMDS dimensions used here, but this would be four dimensional in your example as you set `k = 4`.

Alternative tests are the PERMANOVA method, which is in **vegan** under the pseudonym `adonis()`, distance-based redundancy analysis (`dbrda()` in recently versions of **vegan**), or simply common-or-garden constrained ordinations.

For example, here I use canonical correspondence analysis (CCA) and test the null hypothesis of no `Management` effect

```
mod <- cca(dune ~ Management, data = dune.env)
set.seed(1)
anova(mod)
```

The last line gives:

```
> anova(mod)
Permutation test for cca under reduced model
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999

Model: cca(formula = dune ~ Management, data = dune.env)
         Df ChiSquare      F Pr(>F)   
Model     3   0.60384 2.1307  0.004 **
Residual 16   1.51143                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

These results support the `envfit()` approach used above.

[Do note that I'm not suggesting that any of the choices I made here are truly suitable for the Dutch dune meadow data, I'm just illustrating how the functions in **vegan** work --- I've had too little sleep to recall how to handle the ordinal species abundances in this dataset.]

Answer (score 0):

This can be a  tricky task -- depending on what you mean. However, it is relatively simple to analyse if the change is linear or more complicated. Here an example using `dune` and `dune.env` data in **vegan**:

```
mod <- metaMDS(dune, trace=FALSE)
## Moisture to a matrix of polynomial contrasts
mois <- model.matrix(~ Moisture, dune.env)[,-1] # drop (Intercept)
envfit(mod ~ ., as.data.frame(mois))
```

This shows that only the first degree term or linear change is significant, and the curved (quadratic) and more complicated (cubic) terms are of minor importance. In this example, `Moisture` was defined as an ordered factor in `dune.env`. You must take care that your `Year` also is defined as ordered so that polynomial contrasts will produced, and check that the levels are in the correct order.

There are more complicated tests of significance of directed movement. I think Peter Minchin has published some of those (see *Wetlands* **22,** 1-17; 2002).